# Recursively list all files in a directory including files in symlink directories

Tags: linux

Suppose I have a directory `/dir` inside which there are 3 symlinks to other directories 
`/dir/dir11`, `/dir/dir12`, and `/dir/dir13`. I want to list all the files in `dir` including the ones in `dir11`, `dir12` and `dir13`.

To be more generic, I want to list all files including the ones in the directories which are symlinks. `find .`, `ls -R`, etc stop at the symlink without navigating into them to list further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to only get file name with linux \`find\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456120/how-to-only-get-file-name-with-linux-find)

Answer (score 285, accepted):

The `-L` option to `ls` will accomplish what you want. It dereferences symbolic links.

So your command would be:

```
ls -LR
```

You can also accomplish this with

```
find -follow
```

The `-follow` option directs find to follow symbolic links to directories.

On Mac OS X use

```
find -L
```

as `-follow` has been deprecated.

Comment: -follow is deprecated in favor of -L in newer versions of find.

Comment: @pjz: is there a cross-reference for '-follow deprecated; use -L'?  Somewhat to my considerable surprise, I did find '-L' and '-H' listed in the POSIX / SUS standard at http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/toc.htm, and even more to my surprise no '-follow', so I answered my own question.

Comment: this didn't work for me. first nothing happened then i tried with `-follow`- and it said it couln't find the folder `ollow`

Comment: On OS X 10.10 this works: `find -L .` — I was having the same problem as @S.Matthew_English

Comment: Your answer is good, but I want to `follow` only file paths(full path to file) and not directory path, how can I do it ?

Comment: Is there a way to list files only? No directories.

Comment: `ls -LR1`
where -1 is added to print out one file per line

Answer (score 127):

How about [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree)? `tree -l` will follow symlinks.

**Disclaimer**: I wrote this package.

Comment: How about an arch package ?

Comment: This is a more intuitive view than `ls`. Its also easier to paste around.

Comment: It is a nice interface, but sometimes `tree` is not available and you cannot add it to the system you are trying to explore.

Answer (score 60):

```
find /dir -type f -follow -print
```

`-type f` means it will display real files (not symlinks)

`-follow` means it will follow your directory symlinks

`-print`  will cause it to display the filenames.

If you want a ls type display, you can do the following

```
find /dir -type f -follow -print|xargs ls -l
```

Comment: this produces a prettier display than the `ls -L` option

Answer (score 12):

Using ls:

```
  ls -LR
```

from 'man ls':

```
   -L, --dereference
          when showing file information for a symbolic link, show informa‐
          tion  for  the file the link references rather than for the link
          itself
```

Or, using find:

```
find -L .
```

From the find manpage:

```
-L     Follow symbolic links.
```

If you find you want to only follow a *few* symbolic links (like maybe just the toplevel ones you mentioned), you should look at the -H option, which only follows symlinks that you pass to it on the commandline.

Answer (score 5):

```
find -L /var/www/ -type l

# man find
```

> ```
> -L     Follow  symbolic links.  When find examines or prints information about files, the information used shall be taken from the
> ```
>
> properties of
>                 the file to which the link points, not from the link itself (unless it is a broken symbolic link or find is unable to
>   examine the file to
>                 which  the link points).  Use of this option implies -noleaf.  If you later use the -P option, -noleaf will still be in effect.  If -L is
>                 in effect and find discovers a symbolic link to a subdirectory during its search, the subdirectory pointed to by the
>   symbolic  link  will
>                 be searched.

Answer (score 5):

I knew `tree` was an appropriate, but I didn't have tree installed. So, I got a pretty close alternate [here](http://systembash.com/content/one-line-linux-command-to-print-out-directory-tree-listing/)

```
find ./ | sed -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g;s/--/ |-/'
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls -R -L
```

`-L` dereferences symbolic links. This will also make it impossible to see any symlinks to files, though - they'll look like the pointed-to file.

Answer (score -1):

in case you would like to print all file **contents**:
`find . -type f -exec cat {} +`