# List files recursively in Linux CLI with path relative to the current directory

Tags: linux, unix, recursion, ls

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105212/linux-recursively-list-all-files-in-a-directory-including-files-in-symlink-dire), but I want to include the path relative to the current directory in unix. If I do the following:

```
ls -LR | grep .txt
```

It doesn't include the full paths. For example, I have the following directory structure:

```
test1/file.txt
test2/file1.txt
test2/file2.txt
```

The code above will return:

```
file.txt
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

How can I get it to include the paths relative to the current directory using standard Unix commands?

Comment: This just shows that ls is missing this feature.

Comment: It's a shame all of these solutions require `find` or `tree`. I'm ssh'ing into an android device where I appear to only have `ls`, and none of these other tools :/

Answer (score 347, accepted):

Use find:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print
```

On systems that use GNU find, like most GNU/Linux distributions, you can leave out the -print.

Comment: ...and for that matter you can leave out the '.'

Comment: For absolute paths, use `find $(pwd) -name \*.txt`

Comment: If pattern has part of the directory name should use `-path "*docs/*.txt"` instead of `-name`. `-wholename` is same as `-path`

Comment: Use `-type f` to only return files and not directories, symbolic links, etc.

Comment: `-name "*.txt"` will **NOT** match `file.TXT` — always use `-iname "*.txt"` instead which is case-insensitive.

Comment: Even simpler:

`find -name "*.txt"`

Works on Ubuntu systems at least, which I guess means it works on Debian systems too.

Answer (score 77):

Use `tree`, with `-f` (full path) and `-i` (no indentation lines):

```
tree -if --noreport .
tree -if --noreport directory/
```

You can then use `grep` to filter out the ones you want.

---

If the command is not found, you can install it:

Type following command to install tree command on RHEL/CentOS and Fedora linux:

```
# yum install tree -y
```

If you are using Debian/Ubuntu, Mint Linux type following command in your terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tree -y
```

Comment: any setting to list only the files, and exclude folders?

Answer (score 27):

Try `find`. You can look it up exactly in the man page, but it's sorta like this:

`find [start directory] -name [what to find]`

so for your example

`find . -name "*.txt"`

should give you what you want.

Answer (score 12):

You could use find instead:

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

Answer (score 7):

To get the actual full path file names of the desired files using the find command, use it with the pwd command:

```
find $(pwd) -name \*.txt -print
```

Answer (score 6):

That does the trick:

`ls -R1 $PWD | while read l; do case $l in *:) d=${l%:};; "") d=;; *) echo "$d/$l";; esac; done | grep -i ".txt"`

But it does that by "sinning" with the parsing of `ls`, though, which is considered bad form by the GNU and Ghostscript communities.

Comment: @CAFEBABE: it is considered taboo to parse the results of `ls` because it generally leads to bugs.  The sentence in question was trying to call that out.  It also had a joke in it that I have removed.

Answer (score 4):

```
DIR=your_path
find $DIR | sed 's:""$DIR""::'
```

'sed' will erase 'your_path' from all 'find' results. And you recieve relative to 'DIR' path.

Comment: this is exactly what i need but it still spits out the full path for me?

Comment: don't use the apostrophe's - 
find /tmp | sed s:"/tmp":: | more

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Perl script:

```pl
sub format_lines($)
{
    my $refonlines = shift;
    my @lines = @{$refonlines};
    my $tmppath = "-";

    foreach (@lines)
    {
        next if ($_ =~ /^\s+/);
        if ($_ =~ /(^\w+(\/\w*)*):/)
        {
            $tmppath = $1 if defined $1;    
            next;
        }
        print "$tmppath/$_";
    }
}

sub main()
{
        my @lines = ();

    while (<>) 
    {
        push (@lines, $_);
    }
    format_lines(\@lines);
}

main();
```

usage:

```
ls -LR | perl format_ls-LR.pl
```

Comment: This is a terrible Perl program. It's probably 2-3 times as long, and complicated, than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a shell function, e.g. in your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`:

```sh
filepath() {
    echo $PWD/$1
}

filepath2() {
    for i in $@; do
        echo $PWD/$i
    done
}
```

The first one would work on single files only, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Find the file called "filename" on your filesystem starting the search from the root directory "/". The "filename"

```
find / -name "filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the details come with ls like file size etc in your output then this should work.

```
sed "s|<OLDPATH>|<NEWPATH>|g" input_file > output_file
```

Answer (score 1):

In the [fish](https://fishshell.com/) shell, you can do this to list all pdfs recursively, including the ones in the current directory:

```sh
$ ls **pdf
```

Just remove 'pdf' if you want files of any type.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this functionality like this
Firstly, using the ls command pointed to the targeted directory. Later using find command filter the result from it.
From your case, it sounds like - always the filename starts with a word 
`file***.txt`

```
ls /some/path/here | find . -name 'file*.txt'   (* represents some wild card search)
```

Answer (score 0):

In mycase, with tree command

Relative path

```sh
tree -ifF ./dir | grep -v '^./dir$' | grep -v '.*/$' | grep '\./.*' | while read file; do
  echo $file
done
```

Absolute path

```sh
tree -ifF ./dir | grep -v '^./dir$' | grep -v '.*/$' | grep '\./.*' | while read file; do
  echo $file | sed -e "s|^.|$PWD|g"
done
```