# How to recursively list all files and directories

Tags: linux, shell

Using the tcsh shell on Free BSD, is there a way to recursively list all files and directories including the owner, group and relative path to the file?

ls -alR comes close, but it does not show the relative path in front of every file, it shows the path at the top of a grouping i.e.

```
owner% ls -alR
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 owner  group  102 Feb  1 10:50 .
drwx------+ 27 owner  group  918 Feb  1 10:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x   5 owner  group  170 Feb  1 10:50 subfolder

./subfolder:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  5 owner  group   170 Feb  1 10:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 owner  group   102 Feb  1 10:50 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 owner  group     0 Feb  1 10:50 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 owner  group     0 Feb  1 10:50 file2
```

What I would like is output like:

```
owner group ./relative/path/to/file
```

The [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245698/list-files-recursively-in-linux-with-path-relative-to-the-current-directory) shows the relative path to a file, but does not show the owner and group.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about this:

```
find . -exec ls -dl \{\} \; | awk '{print $3, $4, $9}'
```

Comment: It looks like this fails if there are any spaces in the path because awk will create another field.

There any way to print from $9 to the end of the line?

Comment: Right you are! You *could* read the ls output into a function, shift your way though the arguments and use $@ to read "the rest of the line", but honestly, it's getting messy enough that I'd just write a little Python utility and do it The Right Way instead..

Comment: Or try one of the Perl solutions suggested by slim or Chris.

Comment: Spaces in the path? I thought that this question was tagged "linux"

Comment: @Bruno9779 Spaces in the path are very much allowed in Linux -- try it -- `touch 'my file with spaces'`. Some people discourage it because it's easy to write shell scripts that choke on them -- but you can't prevent apps and users from creating filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 21):

Use **tree**. Few linux distributions install it by default (in these *dark days* of only GUIs :-), but it's always available in the standard repositories. It should be available for *BSD also, see http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/

Use:

```
tree -p -u -g -f -i
```

or

```
tree -p -u -g -f
```

or check the man page for many other useful arguments.

Comment: You can add the `-a` flag to show hidden files as well.

Answer (score 21):

Works in Linux Debian:

```
find $PWD -type f
```

Comment: Works flawlessly on Mac OS X Mountain Lion as well. Thanks.

Comment: If your current directory path contains spaces, surround `$PWD` with double quotes: `find "$PWD" -type f`

Comment: Just in case, it also works on Git Bash from GitHub for Windows.

Comment: Not only does this work with macOS out of the box, but it's also nice, short and memorable. Though I realise this solution doesn't list owner and group. For this you'd need one of the other more verbose solutions.

Answer (score 10):

`find` comes close:

```
find . -printf "%u %g %p\n"
```

There is also "%P", which removes the prefix from the filename, if you want the paths to be relative to the specified directory.

Note that this is GNU find, I don't know if the BSD find also supports -printf.

Comment: BSD find indeed doesn't support -printf, but it's easy enough to install GNU find to ~/bin/gnufind ;)

Answer (score 8):

You've already got an answer that works, but for reference you should be able to do this on the BSDs (I've tested it on a mac) :

```
find . -ls
```

Answer (score 4):

If you fancy using Perl don't use it as a wrapper around shell commands. Doing it in native Perl is faster, more portable, and more resilient. Plus it avoids ad-hoc regexes.

```
use File::Find;
use File::stat;

find (\&myList, ".");

sub myList {
   my $st = lstat($_) or die "No $file: $!";

   print  getgrnam($st->gid), " ", 
          getpwuid($st->uid), " ", 
          $File::Find::name, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way I found was this:

ls -lthr /path_to_directory/*

" * " - represents levels.

```
Ajiths-MBP:test ajith$ ls -lthr *
test2:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 ajith  staff     0B Oct 17 18:22 test2.txt

test3:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 ajith  staff     0B Oct 17 18:22 test3.txt

test1:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 ajith  staff     0B Oct 17 18:21 test1.txt
drwxr-xr-x  3 ajith  staff    96B Oct 17 18:22 test1_sub_dir


Ajiths-MBP:test ajith$ ls -lthr */*
-rw-r--r--  1 ajith  staff     0B Oct 17 18:21 test1/test1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ajith  staff     0B Oct 17 18:22 test2/test2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ajith  staff     0B Oct 17 18:22 test3/test3.txt

test1/test1_sub_dir:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 ajith  staff     0B Oct 17 18:22 test1_sub_file.txt
```

Answer (score -4):

Use a shell script. Or a Perl script. Example Perl script (because it's easier for me to do):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
foreach(`find . -name \*`) {
  chomp;
  my $ls = `ls -l $_`;
  # an incomprehensible string of characters because it's Perl
  my($owner, $group) = /\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S)+/;
  printf("%-10s %-10s %s\n", $owner, $group, $_);
}
```

Perhaps a bit more verbose than the other answers, but should do the trick, and should save you having to remember what to type. (Code untested.)

Comment: Looks like the OP wanted an answer "[u]sing the tcsh shell on Free BSD".