# How to copy all file paths within a folder to a .txt in mac

Tags: macos, terminal, filepath

So I know how to do this on windows using the cmd, I am wondering if this is possible on mac to copy all the file paths within a folder / nested folders into a .txt file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recursively list all files and directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501367/how-to-recursively-list-all-files-and-directories)

Comment: @str is that not refering to linux?

Comment: No not necessarily. The first answer works perfectly on Mac OS.

Comment: `find . -type d > result.txt` should do the trick

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès would you mind just quickly explaining what each part does?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès any ideas how to narrow it to just one folder?

Comment: Hey wait a minute, it seems that you don't dig by yourself, so now read the manuals `man find` and have a look at shell redirections on internet.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès im new to mac, all i need is this this functionality for a customer then i wont be touching it again

Comment: This ain't a good reason, SO is not a "please, makes it for me" platform. I gave you hint-solution, now dig into it.

Comment: hence why i asked if you could explain what they meant so I could try figure it out

Comment: No worries got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved using

```
find /Users/Allington/Desktop/Client -type f > result.txt
```

Returns

```
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/.DS_Store
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client account 1/Screen Shot 2016-12-14 at 16.07.34.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client account 1/Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 12.13.32.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client account 1/Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 15.15.27.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client account 1/Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 15.15.42.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client Account 2/Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 14.33.32.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client Account 2/Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 14.33.40.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client Account 2/Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 14.47.41.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client Account 2/Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 15.15.51.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client Account 3/landingBannerimg.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client Account 3/Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 14.57.14.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client Account 3/Screen Shot 2017-01-10 at 15.15.06.png
/Users/Allington/Desktop/Client/Client Account 3/Screen Shot 2017-01-12 at 13.03.57.png
```