# How to get the relative path for each file in a directory tree based on specified folder path?

Tags: batch-file

I want to loop recursively through a directory and get the file names with full file path and additionally with path relative to the base folder path. For example, a file located in `D:\foo\bar\a\b\file.txt` has the  relative path `bar\a\b\`.

I'm using this code right now which does not work as expected:

```
FOR /R D:\Download\758_DATA\ %%F IN (*) DO (
    SET B = %%~pF
    Set B=%B:~-6%  ::take substring of the path
    ECHO.%B%
    ECHO %%F 
    ECHO.
)
```

Comment: This question is very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8385454/1012053. There exists a good solution there for determining the relative path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish, but at least this will give you a good starting point:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set rootdir=D:\download

for /R %rootdir% %%F in (*) do (
    set "B=%%~pF"
    set "B=!B:~10!"
    echo Full   : %%F
    echo Partial: !B!
    echo(
)

endlocal
```

Since you're modifying a variable within a loop, you need to tell the command interpreter that you want to allow variables to be "expanded with delay". This is what the [setlocal enabledelayedexpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is for. Then you can use `!` as a variable delimiter instead of `%`, and variables written as such will be expanded at runtime. This is necessary because the `for` loop will be called like it is one single call. (You can see this when you leave out the `echo off`.)

**Edit**: Revised example which includes automatic cut off:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "rootdir=%~f1"
if not defined rootdir set "rootdir=%CD%"
set "rootdir=%rootdir:/=\%"
if "%rootdir:~-1%" == "\" set "rootdir=%rootdir:~0,-1%"
set "foo=%rootdir%"
set cut=
:loop
if defined foo (
    set /A cut+=1
    set "foo=!foo:~1!"
    goto :loop
)
echo Root dir: %rootdir%
echo strlen  : %cut%

rem also remove leading /
set /A cut+=1

for /R "%rootdir%" %%F in (*) do (
    set "B=%%~fF"
    rem take substring of the path
    set "B=!B:~%cut%!"
    echo Full    : %%F
    echo Partial : !B!
    echo(
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 16):

To get relative paths you can use variable substitution together with delayed expansion, like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R . %%f in (*) do (
  set B=%%f
  echo Relative !B:%CD%\=!
)
```

I'm using current directory (%CD%) as root directory here.

Comment: This answer **won't work in root directory**, because `!B:%CD%\=!` expands to `!B:C:\\=!`.

Comment: %CD% built-in variable is inconsistent in a way it includes trailing backslash only for root directory. To avoid this problem it's possible to normalize _base path_ with another snippet:
 `if "%BASE:~-1%" == "\" set BASE=%BASE:~0,-1%`