# Changing all files' extensions in a folder with one command on Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, jpeg

How can I use the Windows command line to change the extensions of thousands of files to `*****.jpg`?

Comment: what do you mean by changing all extensions as *****.jpg? does it means all files extensions to jpg?   if yes use ren *.* *.jpg

Comment: what operating system?  How do you want to change them?

Comment: @bryce off course windows operating system..

Answer (score 377, accepted):

You can use `ren` (as in *rename*):

```
ren *.XXX *.YYY
```

And of course, switch XXX and YYY for the appropriate extensions. It will change **from** XXX **to** YYY. If you want to change all extensions, just use the wildcard again:

```
ren *.* *.YYY
```

One way to make this work recursively is with the `FOR` command. It can be used with the `/R` option to recursively apply a command to matching files. For example:

`for /R %x in (*.txt) do ren "%x" *.renamed`

will change all `.txt` extensions to `.renamed` recursively, starting in the current directory.
`%x` is the variable that holds the matched file names.

And, since you have thousands of files, make sure to wait until the cursor starts blinking again indicating that it's done working.

Note: this works only on cmd. Won't work on Powershell or Bash

Comment: *.XXX will change files for that particular extension (means it will rename all files with extension XXX)

Comment: @keyser5053 also can i get a report about the action made here.. with using `ren *.* *.jpg > E:\Log\Cmd\ExtChange\ext.txt`?

Comment: And how about recursive replacement in all sub-dirs?

Comment: @NightElfik I added a recursive example that uses `FOR`

Comment: @MonaJalal In cmd.exe on Windows?

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in powershell, but it worked fine in cmd.exe. Just so that others are aware.

Comment: `ren` not found in my CMD console.

Comment: When doing a wildcard match, you need to include the match in the target filename: `ren "*.html" "#1.pug"`

Answer (score 36):

on CMD

type

```
ren *.* *.jpg
```

*.* will select all files, and rename to * (what ever name they have) plus extension to jpg

Answer (score 13):

Rename behavior is sometimes 'less than intuitive'; for example...

ren *.THM *.jpg will rename your THM files to have an extension of .jpg.  eg:  GEDC003.THM will be GEDC003.jpg

ren *.THM *b.jpg will rename your THM files to *.THMb.jpg.  eg:  GEDC004.THM will become GEDC004.THMb.jpg

ren *.THM *.b.jpg will rename your THM files to *.b.jpg eg:  GEDC005.THM will become GEDC005.b.jpg

Answer (score 7):

NOTE: not for Windows

Using ren-1.0 the correct form is:

```
"ren *.*" "#2.jpg"
```

From `man ren`

> The replacement pattern is another filename with embedded wildcard
>   indexes, each
>          of  which consists of the character # followed by a digit from 1 to 9.  In the new name of a
>          matching file, the wildcard indexes are replaced by the actual characters that  matched  the
>          referenced  wildcards  in  the original filename.

and

> Note  that  the  shell  normally  expands the wildcards * and ?, which
>   in the case of ren is undesirable.  Thus, in most cases it is
>   necessary to enclose the search pattern  in  quotes.

Comment: I had to use #1: ren "*.csv" "#1.json"

Comment: `man ren`? The question was about Windows/`cmd`. Do those now provide `man` pages? What is `ren-1.0` and how can we view its `man` page in context?

Answer (score 6):

thats simple

```
ren *.* *.jpg
```

try this in command prompt

Answer (score 4):

For my windows, `ren` command wasn't working. So, I googled a little bit and wrote a universal solution in bash. You can try running it in on `git bash` from windows and it also runs on linux shell.

```
for f in `find * -type f | grep .png`; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.png}.jpg"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Rename multiple file extensions:

You want to change `ringtone1.mp3`, `ringtone2.mp3` to `ringtone1.wav`, `ringtone2.wav`

Here is how to do that:
I am in d drive on command prompt (CMD) so I use:

```
d:\>ren *.* *.wav
```

This is just an example of file extensions, you can use any type of file extension like WAV, MP3, JPG, GIF, bmp, PDF, DOC, DOCX, TXT this depends on what your operating system.

And, since you have thousands of files, make sure to wait until the cursor starts blinking again indicating that it's done working.

Answer (score 3):

Just for people looking to do this in batch files, this code is working:

```
FOR /R "C:\Users\jonathan\Desktop\test" %%f IN (*.jpg) DO REN "%%f" *.png
```

In this example all files with .jpg extensions in the C:\Users\jonathan\Desktop\test directory are changed to *.png.

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem with a designer delivering images without extension (apple mac sometimes does it). So use can use

```
ren *. *.jpg
```

to add an extension, so that a windows user can use the files.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was useful for me. I had to remove all the files extensions, but I didn't know that syntax with empty extension on right side of the dot. I executed `ren *.* *.` and it remove all the extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Use `cmd` not `powershell`, then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a directory with 800+ files ending with `.StoredProcedure.sql` (they were scripted with [SSMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio)).

The solutions posted above didn't work. But I came up with this:

<sub>(Based on answers to [batch programming - get relative path of file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8487489/3258851))</sub>

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*) do (
  set B=%%f
  set B=!B:%CD%\=!
  ren "!B!" "!B:.StoredProcedure=!"
)
```

The above script removes the substring `.StoredProcedure` from the filename. I'm sure it can be adapted to cover more cases, ask for input and be overall more generic.

Comment: replace your two `set` commands with this single one: `set "B=%%~nxf"`. (`%%~nxf` is **n**ame and e**x**tension of `%%f`). `%cd%` might be invalid, when you do it recursive.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is so old, but i've landed on it , and the provided answers didn't works for me on powershell 
so after searching found this solution

to do it in powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Demo -Filter *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, ".old")}
```

credit goes to http://powershell-guru.com/powershell-tip-108-bulk-rename-extensions-of-files/

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is this one(cd to the folder first):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.old | Rename-Item -NewName {[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, ".new")}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to rename files using the [renamer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/renamer) npm package.

below is an example of renaming files extensions

```
renamer -d --path-element ext --find ts --replace js *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to rename into *.jpg:

```
forfiles /S /M *.* /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname.jpg"
```