# How to convert cfm extension file to CSV files?

Tags: coldfusion

I have some **.cfm** files and i need to convert it into **CSV** files , i know using **STATA** we can do it, but since it is paid and i dont usually use STATA more often so don't wanna buy it, is there any alternative way to convert these types of files into csv file?

Comment: What is in the .cfm files that would make them usable a .csv files? Surely, there can't be CFML in those files.

Comment: `.cfm` files are used to program webpages (and other things). `.csv` is just data. These are two different things. ColdFusion can read and write csv files

Comment: this is the link for a file contains all the variables name which should be on top in csv file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RgIkeHvyt-0S0DVEGLMQe69Ewpo1hIkj  and this file contain the data for one year foe each variable https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xZ8JAHKPN1rfWoQ-ceKevuLUPrUQ3yWs  i have multiple these file(one file for one year data)

Comment: @ScottStroz no there is not CFML, it contains data, please see the comment above

Comment: So you're trying to extract the headers from one file and then use them as the headers for your data files? I don't have ability to access Drive right now, so I can't see your source files, but can you just rename the files to .csv? What are you trying to do with these files? Are you trying to duplicate the behavior of STATA for statistical analysis?

Comment: Also, since I can't see your Drive files, make sure there is no PII or other sensitive info in any of those files. Looking at the STATA site, it talks about being used by researchers for statistical analysis. Including biomed fields.

Comment: When your .cfm files contain CSV-Data, your question seems a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885241/changing-all-files-extensions-in-a-folder-with-one-command-on-windows

Comment: I am not finding any way to use the data, the document which comes with the data have a procedure to convert it into .DTA files using Do-file editor in stata, since i dont have stata, how am i supposed to do this, is there any alternative way to convert it into .DTA files  cause i think i can convert .DTA to .CSV, any suggestions?

Comment: I looked at the file you attached. It seemed to be space-delimited, but it didn't have an identifier for an end of line. How can you tell when your data has a new line? Is this the only file they offer? A better delimited file would make it easier to parse.