# How to change extension from en.srt to .srt in command prompt

Tags: cmd

I have a list of `en.srt` files in my folder. I need to convert them to `.srt` extension.

For example
*Criminal Minds - 1x01 - Extreme Aggressor.**en**.srt* to *Criminal Minds - 1x01 - Extreme Aggressor.srt*

Tried the below command and it didn't work,

```
ren *.en.srt *.srt
```

Renaming extension like `ren *.srt *.srv` works. ([Changing all files' extensions in a folder with one command on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9885241/17447))

Would like to know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: Not tested: `for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir *.en.srt /A-D /B 2^>nul') do for %J in ("%~nI") do @echo ren "%I" "%~nJ%~xI"` Modify `@echo ren` to `@ren` if the output list of `ren` commands looks right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simply though clumsy method is to rename the files twice – first remove `.srt`, then change `.en` to `.srt` (given that there are no other files `*.en`):

```cmd
ren "*.en.srt" "*." & ren "*.en" "*.srt"
```

---

A more elegant solution is the one provided by user [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61462243/how-to-change-extension-from-en-srt-to-srt-in-command-prompt#comment108724861_61462243):

```cmd
@for /F "eol=| delims=" %I in ('dir "*.en.srt" /B /A:-D 2^> nul') do @for %J in ("%~nI") do @ren "%~I" "%~nJ%~xI"
```

In a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) this code would look similar to this (note the necessarily doubled `%`-signs):

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Loop through all matching files:
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "*.en.srt" /B /A:-D 2^> nul') do (
    rem /* There are `~`-modifiers for `for` meta-variables that allow to split file names:
    rem    `~n` returns the base name, so the (last) extension becomes removed;
    rem    `~x` returns the extension (including the leading `.`);
    rem    therefore, `%%~nI` is the original file name with `.srt` removed, hence
    rem    ending with `.en`, and `%%~xI` is the original extension `.srt`;
    rem    another loop is used to also split off `.en` from `%%~nI`: */
    for %%J in ("%%~nI") do (
        rem /* Now `%%~J` returned the same as `%%~nI`, but `%%~nJ` removes `.en`;
        rem    so finally, rename the file to `%%~nJ` plus the original extension `.srt`: */
        ren "%%~I" "%%~nJ%%~xI"
    )
)
```

---

Following the thorough thread [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874) on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), I found out that there is a way using a single `ren` command:

```cmd
ren "*.en.srt" "?????????????????????????????????????????.srt"
```

However, you need to make sure to have enough `?`, namely as many as there are characters in longest matching file name without `.en.srt`; otherwise, file names become truncated. You can avoid truncation by replacing the same sequence of `?` instead of `*`, so longer file names are not renamed at all:

```cmd
ren "?????????????????????????????????????????.en.srt" "?????????????????????????????????????????.srt"
```

Anyway, this only works when the original file names do not contain any more `.` besides the two in `.en.srt`; otherwise, everything behind the first `.` becomes removed and (finally replaced by `srt`).

Answer (score 1):

Not difficult in PowerShell to identify the files and replace the end of the filename with a regex. When you are confident that the files will be renamed correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` command.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Path '.' -Filter '*.en.srt' |" ^
    "ForEach-Object {" ^
        "Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $($_.FullName -replace 'en.srt$','srt') -WhatIf" ^
    "}"
```

Of course, it would be easier if the command shell were PowerShell. BTW, this exact same code would work on Linux and Mac without change.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path '.' -Filter '*.en.srt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $($_.FullName -replace 'en.srt$','srt') -WhatIf
    }
```

Comment: both worked. thanks. do you the reason why `ren` didn't work. I suspect its cos of the `.` in between. Is there a way to encode it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a `cmd` at my disposition but I would guess that

```
ren *.en.srt *.tmp
ren *.tmp *.srt
```

works

Comment: This renames the files to `*.en.tmp` temporarily and then bck to `*.en.srt`...