# Recursively Echo Relative Path In A Batch

Tags: batch-file, echo, relative-path, directory

I've seen a lot of posts similar to this but none of them answer my question or they simply do not work for me.  I am trying to loop through a directory and echo out the relative path of all files in that directory.

My Directory:

```
- Name
  - TestA
    * Subfolder
      - Test.txt
    * Test2.txt
    * Test3.txt
  - TestB
    * Test4.txt
```

What I want it to output:

Name/TestA/Subfolder

Name/TestA

Name/TestA

Name/TestB

I tried this post: [batch programming - get relative path of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487489/batch-programming-get-relative-path-of-file) but it only works for the Subfolder case and even then it cut off everything after Subf.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set ParentPath=C:\Temp
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`dir "%ParentPath%\Name\*.txt" /ON /B /S`) do (
   rem Get drive and path of found text file.
   set "RelativePath=%%~dpI"
   rem Remove the path of parent folder from path of file.
   set "RelativePath=!RelativePath:%ParentPath%=!"
   rem Remove the backslash at beginning and end of the remaining path.
   set "RelativePath=!RelativePath:~1,-1!"
   rem Replace every backslash by a slash character.
   set "RelativePath=!RelativePath:\=/!"
   echo !RelativePath!
   rem echo is the relative path of file
   rem echo %%~nxI
   echo.
)
endlocal
```

outputs

```
Name/TestA

Name/TestA

Name/TestA/Subfolder

Name/TestB
```

As you can see the order of the relative paths is not as you requested.

Is the order important for you?