# batch: get relative filepath of files

Tags: batch-file

I need to get the relative filepath of files with bat.

The folder structure

```
file.bat
- folder1
-- subfolder1
----- abc.image
----- def.image
-- subfolder2
---- more.image
- folder2
-- subfolder1
---- alsoimages.image
-- subfolder2
```

For abc.image, I'd like to get the name of the folder (here e.g. folder1) and the combination folder+subfolder (here e.g. folder1/subfolder1)

I looked at this post: [batch programming - get relative path of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487489/batch-programming-get-relative-path-of-file)
 but I cant make it work for me. The output keeps giving me too many hierachies.

What I want to do ultimately is this:

```
set "prefix=td"
set "file=list_of_images.xml"

echo ^<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?^> > %file%
echo ^<files^> >>  %file%

    for /r %%x in (*.image) do ( 

        echo ^<file folder="(here e.g. folder1)" subfolder="(here e.g. folder1/subfolder1)" id="%prefix%%%~nx" type="image" /^> >>  %file%
    )

echo  ^</files^> >>  %file%
```

Thanks for help and tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%a in ('
    xcopy ".\*.image" "%temp%" /s /e /l 
') do if not "%%b"=="" echo(%%b
```

The easiest way to get a list of files with relative paths is to use an `xcopy` command to generate the list (`/l`) of files.

You can also use a `subst` command to create a "virtual" drive letter with the root of the drive pointing to the required starting folder and then use your same code referencing this drive, that now will not retrieve the upper folder structure

**edited** to adapt to comments

```dos
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=\" %%a in ('
    xcopy ".\*.image" "%temp%" /s /e /l 
') do echo folder=%%a subfolder=%%b file=%%c
```

The output from `xcopy` command is in the format

```
.\folder\subfolder\file
```

so, using backslash as delimiter we skip the first token and retrieve the second (folder), third (subfolder) and fourth (file)

Comment: Okay, this one works really well. But how do I get the substrings from folder/folder1/abc.image so that I have "folder1" and "folder1/subfolder1"?

Answer (score 1):

One of next code snippets could help:

```
  for /r %%x in (*.image) do (
      for /F "tokens=1* delims=\" %%G in ("%%~px") do (

        echo "%%~G" "%%~H" "%prefix%%%~nx"

      ) 
  )
```

Splitting to more than one subfolders:

```
  for /r %%x in (*.image) do (
      for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=\" %%G in ("%%~px") do (

        echo "%%~G" "%%~H" %%~I "%prefix%%%~nx"

      ) 
  )
```

And so on...