# windows batch FOR loop to find a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

Pseudo code:

```
path = ".";
for(;;)
{
   if(exist(path + "/file.exe")
       break;
   path += "/..";
}
```

basically, I have a script that is run from a folder that is a few levels deep from the folder that contains file.exe and I need to find what the path is of that folder.

For a quick workaround, I added this to my bat file:

```
set PATH=..;..\..;..\..\..;..\..\..\..;%PATH%
```

is there a proper way to iterate folders and check if a file exist in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like

```
pushd
:loop
if exist file.exe goto :found
set lastdir=%cd%
cd ..
if "%cd%" EQU "%lastdir%" goto :notfound
goto :loop
:notfound
echo file.exe not found!
popd
goto :eof
:found
set file=%cd%\file.exe
popd
```

Answer (score 3):

You can capture the output of DOS commands using the "usebackq" keyword and enclosing the command string in ` characters.  You can then use the DOS dir command with the bare output (/B) and subdirectory search (/S) switches along with your desired filename to produce a fully qualified path string to that filename.  In this example, i have testFile.exe in test/test2 in my current directory.

in test.bat:

```
@FOR /F "usebackq" %%y in (`dir /s /b testFile.exe`) do @echo Filename: %%y
```

my output:

```
Filename: C:\TEST_REMOVE\test\test2\testFile.exe
```

hope it helps!

_ryan

Comment: I got the idea, although I need to do it in opposite order. The testFile.exe is located in TEST_REMOVE and current dir is located somewhere inside test/test2 or maybe a few more level deep and I need to go up to find location of the testFile.exe

Comment: sorry, i misread the question.  this method is no longer elegant; you should go with Harry's solution.

Answer (score 0):

here is a site you can look at that will give you examples on how and where to start

[How to create a batchfile to read all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385454/batch-files-list-all-files-in-a-directory-with-relative-paths)

I would also suggest doing a Google Search- That's what I did to get this link