# How to search files using batch file and get the relative file path not the full path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, file-search

I want to search files with **.log** extension recursively in a directory. I am trying like below command in a batch file.

```
for /R  %%A in (*.log) do echo %%A >> All_logs.txt
```

I tried this also:

```
for /R  %%A in (*.log) do echo %%~nxA >> All_logs.txt
```

But I am either getting full path like this:

```
D:\Folder1\sub_folder1\bootmicro.log
D:\Folder1\sub_folder2\debug.log
```

or

```
bootmicro.log
debug.log
```

respectively.

Since I am running the batch file in the path D:\Folder1, I want search result to be like:

```
sub_folder1\bootmicro.log
sub_folder2\debug.log
```

**Further, in the same batch file, I want to create folders using the resultant file names as below:**

```
sub_folder1_bootmicro_log_Analysis
sub_folder2_debug_log_Analysis
```

or

```
sub_folder1_bootmicro.log_Analysis
sub_folder2_debug.log_Analysis
```

**How can I do this all?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `xcopy` with a relative path you get a list of files to copy (the `/l` means only get the list) with relative paths.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%a in ('
        xcopy /l /s .\*.log "%temp%"
    ') do if not "%%b"=="" echo(%%b
```

The `for /f` loop will process the list removing the starting `.\` (using the backslash as delimiter) for each file in the list.

As the output from `xcopy` will contain and ending line with the number of files, and this line will not have a second token, the `if` has been included to avoid an empty line at the end.

**edited** For the folder creation, delayed expansion will be needed to handle the string replacement, but to prevent problems with `!` included in any of the files/folders names, it needs to be enabled/disabled where needed.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=\" %%a in ('
        xcopy /l /s .\*.log "%temp%"
    ') do if not "%%b"=="" (
        echo(%%b
        set "target=%%b"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%c in ("!target:\=_!") do (
            endlocal
            md "%%~c_Analysis"
        )
    )
```

Comment: Good idea using `xcopy` to get relative paths; I was thinking of using `forfiles` which is capable of returning relative paths (`@relpath`), but there are always annoying quotes around the output; so it'd become quite complicated removing them and building the new relative path as requested...

Comment: @aschipfl, Not very different. Tested from command line `forfiles /m *.log /s /c "cmd /v /q /c for /f tokens^=1^,*^ delims^=\ %a in (@relpath) do set x=\"%b\" & echo md ^!x:\=_^!"`. A perfect valid idea. I tend not to use `forfiles` if there is another alternative because I don't like starting one `cmd` instance for each command. Just my bad habits.

Comment: Your habits are not that bad actually, @MCND ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Similar with forfiles

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`forfiles /s /m *.txt /C "cmd /c echo @relpath"`) do (
  set "myfile=%%~a"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "myfile=!myfile:~2!
  for %%c in ("!myfile:\=_!") do (
    endlocal
    echo md "%%~c_Analysis"
  )
)
Exit /B
```