# How to save to txt file current directory + file names

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which saves all file names in current directory to txt file,

1. i want to save as well directory name.
2. and then put quotes around them
   so output file would look like this:

> "Directory\File_Name"

This what i done so far

```
dir /b %path % > path.txt
```

Comment: Storing quoted file paths in a text file just screams [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the code you posted does not make sense.

Comment: Try the solution provided in [Batch Files: List all files in a directory with relative paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385454)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a shout for this batch file :

```
@echo off
Set "Folder=%~dp0"
Set "Log=%~n0.txt"
If Exist "%Log%" Del "%Log%"
for /f %%f in ('Dir /b /s "%Folder%"') do echo "%%f" >> "%Log%"
Start "" "%Log%"
```

Or something like that as @Ashwani Kumar posted in the comments :

[Batch Files: List all files in a directory with relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385454/batch-files-list-all-files-in-a-directory-with-relative-paths)

```
@echo off
Set "Folder=%~dp0"
Set "Log=%~n0.txt"
If Exist "%Log%" Del "%Log%"
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
SET "r=%__CD__%"
FOR /R . %%F IN (*) DO (
  SET "p=%%F"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO("!p:%r%=!" >> "%Log%"
  ENDLOCAL
)
Start "" "%Log%"
```