# Windows Batch File - Display All Folder & Sub-Folder relative paths

Tags: windows, list, batch-file, directory

I am trying to have a batch file output ONLY the short-name of folders and sub-folders to a file. However, with the example below I am only able to get the fullpath.

```
DIR /S /B /O:N /A:D > FolderList.txt
```

Which will output:

```
X:\Example\Folder 1
X:\Example\Folder 2
X:\Example\Folder 3
X:\Example\Folder 1\Sub-Folder 1
X:\Example\Folder 1\Sub-Folder 2
X:\Example\Folder 2\Sub-Folder 1
```

When the desired output is:

```
Folder 1
Folder 2
Folder 3
Folder 1\Sub-Folder 1
Folder 1\Sub-Folder 2
Folder 2\Sub-Folder 1
```

The issue comes with the `/S` switch that allows the `DIR` command to recurse into sub-folders.

Is there a simple way, using only a Windows Batch File, to output a list of folders and sub-folders in the current directory to a text file?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385454/batch-files-list-all-files-in-a-directory-with-relative-paths

Comment: @Compo how is this a duplication? The question you linked is referring to **files** whereas I need a list of **folders**.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('DIR /S /B /O:N /A:D') DO (
 SET "name=%%a"
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 ECHO(!name:%cd%\=!
 endlocal
)

GOTO :EOF
```

made a little more confusing because you ask for the "short name" then describe the "relative name".

Obviously, name simply `echo`ed to screen. You're aware of how to redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Just to include a solution using a recursive function call approach

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :getSubFolderList "%~1"
    goto :eof

:getSubFolderList folder [prefix]
    for /d %%a in ("%~f1.\*") do for %%b in ("%~2%%~nxa") do (
        echo %%~b
        call :getSubFolderList "%%~fa" "%%~b\"
    )
    goto :eof
```

When called with a starting folder, it will iterate over the list of subfolders, and for each one the subroutine will call itself to handle the descending folders.

The other answers to this question using `echo` to output the folder path use `delayedexpansion`, echoing the content of the variable used without any problem caused by the parser. But the code in this answer does not use delayed expansion, and characters as `&()` in the folder names can be a problem in the `echo` command.

To avoid this problem, the value to `echo` is quoted and wrapped inside a `for` replaceable parameter. That is the reason for the `for %%b` in the code.

To generate a file with the list of folders, the only change needed is, in the first `call` command:

```dos
call :getSubFolderList "%~1" > fileList.txt
```

note: the code in the answer has been written to receive the folder to be processed as the first argument to the batch file. Change `"%~1"` to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a little trick with the old `SUBST` command to make the root folder a drive letter.  Then you can use the FOR command modifiers to drop the drive letter from the variable on output.

```
@echo off

SET "folders=X:\Example"

subst B: "%folders%"
B:

(FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('DIR /S /B /O:N /A:D') do echo %%~pnxG)>"%~dp0folderlist.txt

subst B: /D
```

Now obviously this does not check to make sure that the drive letter B: is available before using it.  Easy enough to add some code to check for a drive letter that is not in use before executing the `SUBST` command.

Comment: You'll need to prepend a `.` to the paths form them to be really relative, like `echo .%%~pnxG`

Answer (score 1):

To confirm my comment with regard the duplicate response:

```cmd
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /L %%A In (1 1 8192) Do If "!__CD__:~%%A,1!" NEq "" Set/A "Len=%%A+1"
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(For /D /R %%A In (*) Do (
    Set "AbsPath=%%A"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo(!AbsPath:~%Len%!
    EndLocal))>FolderList.txt
```