# Windows batch file with loop through subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I didnt succeed writing an approriate batch file and would appreciate some help.

Let's say I have an exe in D:\Test\ called script.exe.
To execute this script.exe it requires an additional argument of a .bin files (e.g. bin01.bin, bin02.bin).

Therefore it would be like: script.exe -i bin01.bin, script.exe -i bin01

I want the script to execute with all .bin files from all subfolders

D:\Test\script.exe
D:\Test\Folder01\bin01.bin
D:\Test\Folder01\bin02.bin
D:\Test\Folder02\bin01.bin
D:\Test\Folder03\bin01.bin

anyone could help me here? 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch Files: List all files in a directory with relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385454/batch-files-list-all-files-in-a-directory-with-relative-paths)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For direct execution from within a command prompt window:

```
for /R "D:\Test" %I in (*.bin) do @D:\Test\script.exe -i "%I"
```

And the same command line for usage in a batch file:

```
@for /R "D:\Test" %%I in (*.bin) do @D:\Test\script.exe -i "%%I"
```

The command **FOR** searches **recursive** in directory `D:\Test` and all subdirectories for files matching the wildcard pattern `*.bin`.

The name of each found file is assigned with full path to case-sensitive loop variable `I`.

**FOR** executes for each file the executable `D:\Test\script.exe` with first argument `-i` and second argument being the name of found file with full path enclosed in double quotes to work for any *.bin file name even those containing a space or one of these characters: `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

`@` at beginning of entire **FOR** command line just tells Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` not to echo the command line after preprocessing before execution to console window as by default.

`@` at beginning of `D:\Test\script.exe` avoids the output of this command to console executed on each iteration of the loop.

Most often the echo of a command line before execution is turned off at beginning of the batch file with `@echo off` as it can be seen below.

```
@echo off
for /R "D:\Test" %%I in (*.bin) do D:\Test\script.exe -i "%%I"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`