# Linux list files recursively ignoring a pattern

Tags: linux, ls

I have exactly the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245698/344286).

Only instead of finding all the `.txt` files, I want a list of all files that are **not** `.txt` files.

Something like

```
$ ls -LR | grep -v .java
```

Which definitely does not do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` as suggested in that post and negate the `-name` condition with `!` to have the other way round:

```sh
find . -type f ! -name "*.txt"
#      ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#   just files        |
#              file names not ending with .txt
```

Comment: `-type f` is also required for me in this case, to find only files. I finally looked for `not` in the find manpage - exclude and inverse aren't present :P

Comment: Trye! Added `-type f`. But then, did this solution work to you with `!`?

Comment: Yes - I just couldn't accept the answer that quickly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?,

```
ls -lr | grep -E -v "*.txt$"
```

I tested it on my end and it worked, -E extended grep

Comment: this works only if the r is a capital R ;) (can't edit answers for less than 6 characters)