# How to list all text files in root and subdirectories using 'ls'

Tags: linux, file, search, ls

I use this to list all text files in d:\ root:
`ls d:\*.txt`
This to list all text files in all sub-directories:
`ls d:\*\*.txt`

How can I list all text files in the root AND in all sub-directories using `ls`?

This doesn't work:
`ls d:/{,**/}*.txt`

edit: in `ls` not in `find`, `grep`, `awk`, `sed` or whatever other search command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files recursively in Linux CLI with path relative to the current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245698/list-files-recursively-in-linux-cli-with-path-relative-to-the-current-directory)

Comment: Why is this tagged `linux`, but using paths that look like `d:\....`??

Comment: NO duplicate! This is about 'ls'. I know there is the 'find' and grep command but in my question I write about 'ls'.  :(

Comment: @WilliamPursell, good question. I'm using windows subsystem for linux (=linux on windows 10).

Comment: @jww I know. I doubted in the beginning. Could not find a better site.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ls **/*.txt`. This is worked in zsh.

or

`ls $(START_DIR)/**/*.txt`

Comment: Yes that works but there is no way to indicate the d:\ directory (the start directory)? --> Edit: It doesn't work.. It doesn't include the text files in root.

Comment: just append the start directory in front. ex. ls ~/home/*/**/*.txt

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I made a mistake. It doesn't include the text files in root.

Comment: @Reman Which shell are you doing this in? Bash requires you to `shopt -s globstar` first

Comment: @thatotherguy the default Windows 10 Shell Command and sometimes the debian bash shell

Comment: They do not share syntax, even if some commands are similar. Please choose one to ask about.

Comment: @J.Z `ls ~/home/*/**/*.txt` does only find .txt files in the 2nd subdirectories (the subdirectory of a subdirectory). Is there no way to indicate to `ls` that all subdirectories need to be searched?

Comment: @thatotherguy Windows shell is my default shell

Comment: @J.Z gives an error...~/home/**/*.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: In bash or zsh, this error will display if there is no matching result. Is there any .txt file under your ~/home directory or its subdirectories?

Comment: @J.Z This (home) directory doesn't exist on my system. I've read these days more and more about `ls`. It seems not to be possible using `ls` to scan all sub directories. Many point to `find.exe` to scan all subdirectories.