# How to only get file name with Linux 'find'?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I'm using find to all files in directory, so I get a list of paths. However, I need only file names. i.e. I get `./dir1/dir2/file.txt` and I want to get `file.txt`

Answer (score 499, accepted):

In GNU `find` you can use `-printf` parameter for that, e.g.:

```
find /dir1 -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: Clearly the *answer*, but it lacks detail.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when I use multiple file types (-o switch)

Comment: find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Comment: @Urchin No reason it shouldn't so long as you have correct logic (i.e. `-o` has lower precedence than implied `-a`, so you will often want to group your `-o` arguments)

Comment: `find ./ -name "*" -printf "%f\n"  | xargs grep "searchName"` This doesn't work, it'll only print: about.php: No such file or directory
grep: site-themes.php: No such file or directory Or `find ./ -name "*"   | xargs grep "searchName"  -printf "%f\n"` still error

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer.

`find -printf "%f\n" -exec echo {} \;` reveals that the original filename is passed forward

Comment: Clearly lacks details where to put target file name "file.txt" in the command.

Comment: @SoulClinic Hence the ‘GNU’ caveat

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on MacOS

Comment: I'm filtering files by user and print it `find ./ -user web -printf '%f\n'` and it only prints file name

Comment: This is significantly faster than Kambus' answer below, by not invoking an `exec` call.

Answer (score 217):

If your find doesn't have a -printf option you can also use basename:

```
find ./dir1 -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

Comment: Quoting the semicolon is another way to disambiguate: `... {} ';'`

Comment: The `exec` call incurs a significant performance overhead versus the `printf` solution above

Answer (score 40):

Use `-execdir` which automatically holds the current file in `{}`, for example:

```
find . -type f -execdir echo '{}' ';'
```

<sup>You can also use `$PWD` instead of `.` (on some systems it won't produce an extra dot in the front).</sup>

If you still got an extra dot, alternatively you can run:

```
find . -type f -execdir basename '{}' ';'
```

---

> `-execdir utility [argument ...] ;`
>
> The `-execdir` primary is identical to the `-exec` primary with the exception that utility will be executed from the directory that **holds the current file**.

When used `+` instead of `;`, then `{}` is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for each invocation of utility. In other words, it'll print all filenames in one line.

Comment: I'm getting `./filename` instead of `filename`. Depending on your needs, it may or may not be fine.

Comment: @user276648 Try with `$PWD` instead of `.`.

Answer (score 37):

If you are using GNU find

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

Or you can use a programming language such as Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -e 'Dir["**/*"].each{|x| puts File.basename(x)}'
```

If you fancy a bash (at least 4) solution

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **; do echo ${file##*/}; done
```

Comment: I was inspired by your answer to help sleske : http://serverfault.com/a/745968/329412

Answer (score 13):

If you want to run some action against the filename only, using `basename` can be tough.

For example this:

```
find ~/clang+llvm-3.3/bin/ -type f -exec echo basename {} \;
```

will just echo basename `/my/found/path`. Not what we want if we want to execute on the filename.

But you can then `xargs` the output. for example to kill the files in a dir based on names in another dir:

```
cd dirIwantToRMin;
find ~/clang+llvm-3.3/bin/ -type f -exec basename {} \; | xargs rm
```

Comment: dont echo - `find ~/clang+llvm-3.3/bin/ -type f -exec basename {} \; `

Answer (score 10):

As others have pointed out, you can combine `find` and `basename`, but by default the `basename` program will only operate on one path at a time, so the executable will have to be launched once for each path (using either `find ... -exec` or `find ... | xargs -n 1`), which may potentially be slow.

If you use the `-a` option on `basename`, then it can accept multiple filenames in a single invocation, which means that you can then use `xargs` without the `-n 1`, to group the paths together into a far smaller number of invocations of `basename`, which should be more efficient.

Example:

```
find /dir1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 basename -a
```

Here I've included the `-print0` and `-0` (which should be used together), in order to cope with any whitespace inside the names of files and directories.

Here is a timing comparison, between the `xargs basename -a` and `xargs -n1 basename` versions.  (For sake of a like-with-like comparison, the timings reported here are after an initial dummy run, so that they are both done after the file metadata has already been copied to I/O cache.)  I have piped the output to `cksum` in both cases, just to demonstrate that the output is independent of the method used.

```
$ time sh -c 'find /usr/lib -type f -print0 | xargs -0 basename -a | cksum'
2532163462 546663

real    0m0.063s
user    0m0.058s
sys 0m0.040s

$ time sh -c 'find /usr/lib -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 basename | cksum' 
2532163462 546663

real    0m14.504s
user    0m12.474s
sys 0m3.109s
```

As you can see, it really is substantially faster to avoid launching `basename` every time.

Comment: Reading the answer from @minusf more thoroughly, I see that on a Mac `basename` will accept multiple filenames without needing any additional command-line arguments. The use of `-a` here is on Linux.  (`basename --version` tells me `basename (GNU coreutils) 8.28`.)

Answer (score 8):

On mac (BSD `find`) use:

```
find /dir1 -type f -exec basename {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

Honestly `basename` and `dirname` solutions are easier, but you can also check this out :

```
find . -type f | grep -oP "[^/]*$"
```

or

```
find . -type f | rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev
```

or

```
find . -type f | sed "s/.*\///"
```

Comment: the `basename` solution did not do it for me, but piping the result into `sed` worked like a charm, thanks for this.

Answer (score 4):

`-exec` and `-execdir` are slow, `xargs` is king.

```sh
$ alias f='time find /Applications -name "*.app" -type d -maxdepth 5'; \
f -exec basename {} \; | wc -l; \
f -execdir echo {} \; | wc -l; \
f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 basename | wc -l; \
f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P 8 basename | wc -l; \
f -print0 | xargs -0 basename | wc -l

     139
    0m01.17s real     0m00.20s user     0m00.93s system
     139
    0m01.16s real     0m00.20s user     0m00.92s system
     139
    0m01.05s real     0m00.17s user     0m00.85s system
     139
    0m00.93s real     0m00.17s user     0m00.85s system
     139
    0m00.88s real     0m00.12s user     0m00.75s system
```

`xargs`'s parallelism also helps.

Funnily enough i cannot explain the last case of `xargs` without `-n1`.
It gives the correct result and it's the fastest `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

(`basename` takes only 1 path argument but `xargs` will send them all (actually 5000) without `-n1`.  does not work on linux and openbsd, only macOS...)

Some bigger numbers from a linux system to see how `-execdir` helps, but still much slower than a parallel `xargs`:

```
$ alias f='time find /usr/ -maxdepth 5 -type d'
$ f -exec basename {} \; | wc -l; \
f -execdir echo {} \; | wc -l; \
f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 basename | wc -l; \
f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P 8 basename | wc -l

2358
    3.63s real     0.10s user     0.41s system
2358
    1.53s real     0.05s user     0.31s system
2358
    1.30s real     0.03s user     0.21s system
2358
    0.41s real     0.03s user     0.25s system
```

Comment: just one more data point: on openbsd in a long running `find` it is `-execdir` that becomes the fastest as creating new processes is a relatively expensive operation.

Answer (score -3):

I've found a solution (on makandracards page), that gives just the newest file name:

```
ls -1tr * | tail -1
```

(thanks goes to Arne Hartherz)

I used it for `cp`:

```
cp $(ls -1tr * | tail -1) /tmp/
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.