# How to get basename of a file in find -exec

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm currently trying to extract and use the filename of the result of a find command.

```sh
 find /var/log/*/* -iname "*.log" -type f -exec echo $(basename -- {}) \;
```

Actual Output:

```sh
/var/log/xyz/log1.log
/var/log/xyz/log2.log
/var/log/xyz/log3.log
/var/log/xyz/log4.log
```

Expected output:

```sh
log1.log
log2.log
log3.log
log4.log
```

Is there a trick or something that a misunderstand in using `-exec` ?

When I execute `echo $(basename -- 'path/to/file.txt')` in a bash it returns correctly `file.txt`

**further details:**

I need to use full path and basename in the result:

My full command looks like the following:

```sh
find /var/log/*/* -iname "*.log" -type f -exec gzip -k -f {} \; -exec gzip -t {}'.gz' \; -exec sh -c "cat {} | grep 'str' > /tmp/$(basename -- {})" \; # and more after
```

In this command, I can't extract the filename and use it. it always return the full path of the file like `/var/log/foo/bar.log`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have Find print just the filenames, not full paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202495/have-find-print-just-the-filenames-not-full-paths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `basename` after `exec` option. Just use `-execdir` option and print `{}` as:

```
find /var/log/*/ -iname '*.log' -execdir printf '%s\n' {} +
```

If you really have to call `basename` then use it as:

```
find /var/log/*/ -iname '*.log' -exec basename -- {} \;
```

---

Based on your comments and edited question it seems you will be better off using `find` result this way:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   echo "$file"
   basename "$file"
   # remaining commands like gzip etc
done < <(find /var/log/*/ -iname '*.log'  -print0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works, but I want to be able to use it in multiple `exec` I'v tryed your code but it didn't do the job :( I'v added further details in my question

Comment: Yeah ! It's works now ! Thanks a lot for your response ! I was strugling with this since yesterday evening !

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
find /your/complete/path -type f -iname "*.log" -printf '%P\n'
```

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov, Just checked attached link and seems `%P` option is not mentioned there, so added my answer here.

Comment: Thanks for you response, but I really need to use `-exec`. I'v added some further informations in my question in order to better explain what I'm tryin to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call basename then use it as:

```sh
find /var/log/\*/\* -iname "*.log" -type f -exec basename '{}' \;
```