# RegEx search on linux filesystem based on filenames

Tags: regex, linux, grep, find, regex-negation

I have tried following command `find . | egrep -v '.*/[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{8}-.'` to recursively search for files (not folders) that are not in the pattern. This also displays folders! What am I missing?

Comment: Obviously `egrep` simply filters out all input lines which match that pattern anywhere in the line.  You could fix that by adding `[^/]*$` to the end of the pattern, but using the search predicates of `find` directly, as suggested in Wiktor's answer, is a much better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` directly with `-not` option:

```sh
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex '.*/[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{8}-[^/]*$' -exec basename {} \;
```

With GNU `find`, you may use

```sh
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex '.*/[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{8}-[^/]*$' -printf "%f\n"
```

*Details*:

- `-type f` - return only file paths
- `-regextype posix-egrep` sets the regex flavor to POSIX ERE
- `-not` reverses the regex result
- `.*/[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{8}-[^/]*$` - matches paths where file names start with three uppercase letters, `-`, eight digits, `-` and then can have any text other than `/` till the end of the string
- `-exec basename {} \;` /  `-printf "%f\n"` only prints the file names without folders (see [Have Find print just the filenames, not full paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9202495/3832970))

Comment: Thank you for your hint!
Do you have another hint that I see only data and no folders?

Comment: @e4c4c1 `-type f ` only outputs files... Or do you mean you only want to see the file names without the folders in the output? Then use `find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -not -regex '.*/[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{8}-[^/]*$' -exec basename {} \;`

Comment: ... or if you are using GNU `find`, use `-printf '%f\n'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was searching for `-type f` in combination with `-exec basename {} \;`, also your whole last command fits! Thank you!