# Linux genisoimage Batch

Tags: linux

So i have the following directories:

/shares/media/movies
/shares/media/series

How can I loop through each directory recursively and whenever it finds a folder called VIDEO_TS, let Genisoimage convert that folder to an iso image, the name of the iso would be the parent folder's name.

Very complex and as I am not a guru with these things, I decided to ask it as question on Stackoverflow.

The command that I use for a single directory:

```
genisoimage -o movie_1.iso -dvd-video /shares/media/movies/Movie 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /tmp/ -type d -name VIDEO_TS
```

for example this looks for any directory named `VIDEO_TS` under `/tmp`

at this point you only need to iterate over the result

```
for file in $(find /tmp/ -type d -name VIDEO_TS);do echo $file;done;
```

in this case the action performed for every match is `echo $file` which simply prints out the name of the record that matches your search, you can easily adapt this to perform any kind of command line task.

Comment: I will have to find a way to get just the parent directory name from $FILE, how would I do that? And the batch automatically breaks directory names with space and special characters, will this be of effect when I use the genisoimage command?

Comment: @NullBy7e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456120/how-to-get-file-only-file-name-with-linux-find

Comment: How is that relevant to what I asked? I already came across that and basename or printf gives me VIDEO_TS as output, obviously...

Comment: This is what I used when doing something similar:

`for file in $(find ./ -type d -name VIDEO_TS);do genisoimage -o $(basename $(dirname $file)).ISO -dvd-video $(dirname $file);done`