# get last directory from a string

Tags: shell, find

I am trying to extract, in linux (tcsh), the last part of a delimited string.

For example:
I have a string that is /dir1/dir2/dir3 and the output should be only dir3.

The complete task I want to implement is:
I want to find directory names that follow a given pattern, but "find"command returns a full path and not only the last directory, which is really what I want. Moreover, the result from the "find"command should be split into an arry to be processed later with a script.

command I am using to find the directory:

```
find path -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "*abc*"
```

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to only get file name with linux \`find\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456120/how-to-only-get-file-name-with-linux-find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the command `basename` :

```
$ basename /dir1/dir2/dir3
dir3
```

> **`man basename`** :
>   Print `NAME` with any leading directory components removed.

This can be combined with `find` as :

```
$ find path -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "*abc" -exec basename {} \;
```

or you can avoid `basename` and just pipe it to `awk` as :

```
$ find path -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "*abc" | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
```

But if you really want to avoid anything and just use `find` you can use the `printf` statement of `find` as :

```
$ find path -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "*abc" -printf "%f\n"
```

> **`man find`**: `%f` File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply,

Output of find command:
mydir1
mydir2
mydir3

I would like to add all of the results to a list/array, so I can use a for loop to iterate through the items.

Best regards,
Pdro