# Print all files with an extension in all subdirectories to a CSV (BASH)

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that handles backup logs. I have month folders which contain subfolders and in those subfolders there are multiple files that have the extension ".ptx".

I want to grab every file ending with .ptx and print this out to a CSV file.

I'm not sure how to approach this as I have pretty limited knowledge but I think I need to use **find** [like in this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617016/copy-all-files-with-a-certain-extension-from-all-subdirectories)

This is where I was at for the month February:

```
if [ -d "/Volumes/NAS/01_PROJECTS/01_SHORTFORM/2024/02_FEB/" ]; then
  
cd /Volumes/NAS/01_PROJECTS/01_SHORTFORM/2024/02_FEB/

printf '%s\n' * > AUDIO_BACKUP_LOG_02_FEB.csv

mv AUDIO_BACKUP_LOG_02_FEB.csv /Volumes/NAS/04_ADMIN/06_BACKUP_LOGS/MONTHS/2024/

echo "Feb completed"

fi
```

I'm not quite sure how to combine **printf** and **find** and also look into all the subdirectories.

Comment: You can divide your problem into two fairly independent tasks: First collecting all the files, and then writing a filename to your CSV. Therefore you better ask two questions here. Especially the CSV part can be tricky: What are the columns of the CSV? What is the field separator of those columns? Note that there are only few characters which can not occur in a filename. In particular, a filename can contain spaces and newlines. The CSV format itself can cope with this, but you need to create the correct syntax to make it valid CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get just the name of the file and strip the directory path you can try something like:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.ptx' -exec basename {} \; > AUDIO_BACKUP_LOG_01_JAN.csv
```

If you want to exclude by mask some files you can try something like:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.ptx' -exec basename {} \; |grep -v '.bak.' > AUDIO_BACKUP_LOG_01_JAN.csv
```

Comment: This worked well thanks! Is there any way to exclude based on file name as well. I'm trying to get rid of any .ptx file that also contain the string `.bak.`. I'm doing this but I think my syntax is incorrect: `find . -type f -iname '*.ptx' ! -iname '.bak.' -exec basename {} \; > AUDIO_BACKUP_LOG_02_FEB.csv`

Comment: Don't add requirements in comments, edit your question to contain all relevant information, but more importantly - don't add requirements after you have answers as that makes it a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) which is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Sorry @EdMorton I'm a bit of a noobie to be honest and discovering/creating problems as I go. Anyway, thanks for teaching me the etiquette.

Comment: @RomeoNinov That exclusion worked perfectly as well, thanks so much for your help

Comment: @LJS, if you are happy with particular answer you can mark it as accepted (the tick on the left of answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` to find all the files matching your extension (and other criteria) and then use the `-print` option to output the filenames which you can pipe trough an output file as needed:

```bash
find . -type f -iname '*.csv' -print > /tmp/output.txt
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! I tweaked to the following:

`find . -type f -iname '*.ptx' -print > AUDIO_BACKUP_LOG_02_FEB.csv`

This works quite well but gives me both the subdirectory and the filename like so:

`./01_02_24_SubdirectoryName/01_02_24_FileName.ptx`

I'm trying to work out how to get just the filename currently.

Comment: Ah well to bad my someone already duplicate my answer with the addition. But yea, you can use that exec basename to [only get the filename itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456120/how-to-only-get-file-name-with-linux-find).