# Loop through all the files with a specific extension

Tags: bash, file, glob

```
for i in $(ls);do
    if [ $i = '*.java' ];then
        echo "I do something with the file $i"
    fi
done
```

I want to loop through each file in the current folder and check if it matches a specific extension. The code above doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: What about `for i in $(ls *.java); do echo "do something with file $i"; done`?

Comment: there is no way to fix that if statement?

Comment: You are comparing `$i` to the literal string "*.java"; pattern expansion is not performed here.

Comment: To fix the if statement as you have it, use `if [[ $i == *.java ]]; then` .. (note the double [[]]s and unquoted *.java).

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- accept @chepner's answer

Comment: @glennjackman Yes but this does not fail only due to bad file names. See my answer below.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

No fancy tricks needed:

```
for i in *.java; do
    [ -f "$i" ] || break
    ...
done
```

The guard ensures that if there are no matching files, the loop will exit without trying to process a non-existent file name `*.java`.

In `bash` (or shells supporting something similar), you can use the `nullglob` option
to simply ignore a failed match and not enter the body of the loop.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *.java; do
    ...
done
```

---

Some more detail on the `break`-vs-`continue` discussion in the comments. I consider it somewhat out of scope whether you use `break` or `continue`, because what the first loop is trying to do is distinguish between two cases:

1. `*.java` had no matches, and so is treated as literal text.
2. `*.java` had at least one match, and that match might have included an entry named `*.java`.

In case #1, `break` is fine, because there are no other values of `$i` forthcoming, and `break` and `continue` would be equivalent (though I find `break` more explicit; you're exiting the loop, not just waiting for the loop to exit passively).

In case #2, you still have to do whatever filtering is necessary on any possible matches. As such, the choice of `break` or `continue` is less relevant than which *test* (`-f`, `-d`, `-e`, etc) you apply to `$i`, which IMO is the wrong way to determine if you entered the loop "incorrectly" in the first place.

That is, I don't want to be in the position of examining the value of `$i` *at all* in case #1, and in case #2 what you do with the value has more to do with your business logic for each file, rather than the logic of *selecting* files to process in the first place. I would prefer to leave that logic to the individual user, rather than express one choice or the other in the question.

---

As an aside, `zsh` provides a way to do this kind of filtering in the glob itself. You can match *only* regular files ending with `.java` (and disable the default behavior of treating unmatched patterns as an error, rather than as literal text) with

```
for f in *.java(.N); do
  ...
done
```

With the above, you are *guaranteed* that if you reach the body of the loop, then `$f` expands to the name of a regular file. The `.` makes `*.java` match only regular files, and the `N` causes a failed match to expand to nothing instead of producing an error.

There are also other such *glob qualifiers* for doing all sorts of filtering on filename expansions. (I like to joke that `zsh`'s glob expansion replaces the need to use `find` at all.)

Comment: How to change this to be able to loop over all *.java and *.cpp files?

Comment: The simplest way is to add another pattern: `for i in *.java *.cpp; do`. If you have extended patterns enabled in `bash` with `shopt -s extglob`, you can write `for i in *.@(java|cpp); do`.

Comment: It will if it actually matches any files. You need to use `shopt -s nullglob` so that a non-matching pattern expands to the empty sequence rather than be treated literally.

Comment: Does this loop through *.java files in current directory?

Comment: @zygimantus yes it should, so long as current directory is where the script is running from. If you are not in the directory you want to be though, you should `cd` to that directory before you start the `for` loop

Comment: I think this fails if there is no *.java files present, then it treats it as a string

Comment: @puk It depends on your shell options. By default, a non-matching pattern is treated as a literal string. You can set `nullglob` to have it treated as an empty sequence, or set `failglob` to have it treated as an error. (If you set both, `failglob` takes precedence.)

Comment: @chepner It might be useful for non experts to have this indicated in the answer as someone may copy paste it and find it not working. A perfect example would be someone who is converting all "*.jpg" files to "*.png" before carrying out a crucial function

Comment: Instead of `[ -f "$i" ] || break`, we need `[ -f "$i" ] || continue`, right?

Comment: I guess `break` and `continue` would have the same effect with just one pattern which doesn't match. With multiple patterns (`for i in *.java *.foo *.bar`, e.g.), you would want `continue` to move on to the next pattern.

Comment: @codeforester is right, `continue` is necessary. If there is a plain file named `b.java` and a directory named `a.java`, then the loop can be terminated by `break` before it reaches `b.java`.

Comment: This `nullglob` default setting is the most counter intuitive thing in bash I have seen so far. And it contains a lot of non intuitive things...

Comment: @kap Like so many other things, it's probably the result of having to support historical decisions that assumed (I'm guessing) a user wouldn't use a glob if they didn't expect it to produce at least one match. The thinking (again, I'm guessing) was that it was simpler to let whatever command was going use the output to produce an error than trying to deal with failures to match themselves.

Comment: @chepner May I ask why the editing of `break` to `continue` was rejected as it "deviates from the original intent of the post"? By changing the keyword to `continue` the guard will still `ensure that (...) the loop will exit without trying to process a non-existent file name *.java`. Right now, if there is a directory named `a.java`, the file `b.java` will not be  considered by the loop, but with `continue` it _will_ be considered. Therefore I would consider the edit to have the same intent, but it improves the loop imo

Comment: I might consider switch to using `-e` to allow any kind of file-system entry to be processed, but I would still prefer to use `break`. The point of the answer, though, was to show that you could use a pattern to match the desired files, rather than iterating over *everything* in the current directory. I don't really see the exact details of the filtering being in the scope of the answer.

Comment: The original poster stated "I want to loop through **each** file in the current folder", so not iterating over _everything_ in the current folder does not answer the question then. Others having his/her problem and reading this answer might think it actually considers _all_ files in the folder, when it in fact might not consider all files. (BTW I do really appreciate both your post and your quick answer :))

Comment: Really, the issue is not so much over `break` or `continue`, but in whether `*.java` represents the failure of a pattern to expand or an *actual* entry named `*.java`. If it's not a real entry, then you want to break; otherwise, who knows what you want to do. If I'm going to edit the answer, I'd like something that addresses the success-vs-failure of the expansion, not what you do with `$i`. (That's why I really prefer the `nullglob` answer; it lets you not enter the loop at all rather than specify how to terminate the loop early when necessary.)

Answer (score 33):

Recursively add subfolders,

```
for i in `find . -name "*.java" -type f`; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: instead of `find . -name "*.java" -type f -exec echo \{\} \;`  to avoid misparsing of the output of `find`

Comment: And if you don't, at least you should quote `"$i"` inside the loop.

Comment: This won't work if any of the files have whitespace in their name.

Comment: @codeforester I had exactly that issue and I've fixed it using the method from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/343753/551184

Comment: If there is a space in the file this falls over completely.

Answer (score 24):

Loop through all files ending with: `.img`, `.bin`, `.txt` suffix, and print the file name:

```
for i in *.img *.bin *.txt;
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Or in a recursive manner (find also in all subdirectories):

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.img" -o -name "*.bin" -o -name "*.txt"`;
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: according to `man find`: `-o (meaning logical OR)`

Comment: I like the top solution of yours and upvoted it but I get an error if I do not have a file with that particular extension. Is there something I can do to ignore an extension if not found?

Answer (score 14):

the correct answer is @chepner's

```
EXT=java
for i in *.${EXT}; do
    ...
done
```

however, here's a small trick to check whether a filename has a given extensions:

```
EXT=java
for i in *; do
    if [ "${i}" != "${i%.${EXT}}" ];then
        echo "I do something with the file $i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: how would it be with a variable `ext` instead of `.java`?

Answer (score 3):

as @chepner says in his comment you are comparing $i to a fixed string.

To expand and rectify the situation you should use [[ ]] with the regex operator =~

eg:

```
for i in $(ls);do
    if [[ $i =~ .*\.java$ ]];then
        echo "I want to do something with the file $i"
    fi
done
```

the regex to the right of =~ is tested against the value of the left hand operator and should not be quoted, ( quoted will not error but will compare against a fixed string and so will most likely fail"

but @chepner 's answer above using glob is a much more efficient mechanism.

Comment: how would it be with a variable `ext` instead of `.java`?

Comment: ack, no need for a regular expression: `if [[ $i == *.java ]]` or `if [[ $i == *.$ext ]]`. But [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: a beautiful solution, since I could do the search in subdirectories by simply using 
`for i in $(ls -lR); do ...`, or if you want the relative path of the file : `for i in $(find -L .);do ...` with the help of another good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/105249/6045793

Answer (score 3):

I agree withe the other answers regarding the correct way to loop through the files. However the OP asked:

> The code above doesn't work, do you know why?

Yes!

An excellent article  [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)  explains in detail that among other differences, you cannot use `expression matching` or `pattern matching` within the `test` command (which is shorthand for `[` )

```
Feature            new test [[    old test [           Example

Pattern matching    = (or ==)    (not available)    [[ $name = a* ]] || echo "name does not start with an 'a': $name"

Regular Expression     =~        (not available)    [[ $(date) =~ ^Fri\ ...\ 13 ]] && echo "It's Friday the 13th!"
matching
```

So this is the reason your script fails. If the OP is interested in an answer with the `[[` syntax (which has the disadvantage of not being supported on as many platforms as the `[` command), I would be happy to edit my answer to include it.

EDIT: Any protips for how to format the data in the answer as a table would be helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution to be quite handy. It uses the `-or` option in `find`:

```
find . -name \*.tex -or -name "*.png" -or -name "*.pdf"
```

It will find the files with extension `tex`, `png`, and `pdf`.