# bash scripting with echo, pipe, and variables

Tags: bash, echo, sh, var

I'd like to retrieve the result of a

```
echo $1/*.pem
```

and put the result in a array.

I tried:

```
a = echo $1/*.pem | grep pem  *
```

or

```
a = echo $1/*.pem
```

It fails.

When I do:

```
echo $1/*.pem
```

it display the good result

```
/opt/tmp/a.pem /opt/tmp/ab.pem
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: loop through all the files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505047/bash-loop-through-all-the-files-with-a-specific-extension)

Answer (score 1):

You can let `bash` do the expansion and use parenthesis to cast an array without the use of `echo`:

```
a=( "$1"/*.pem )
echo "${a[@]}"
```

You can use `echo` but you'll have to use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) to reassign the output of the `echo` command to the array, and you will have problems if you have spaces in the name of your path:

```
a=( $(echo $1/*.pem) )
```

Comment: I'd also recommend double-quoting the array when you use it (e.g. `echo "${a[@]}"`) -- again, this is to avoid problems with spaces or other shell metacharacters in the filenames. Double-quoting variable references is almost always a good idea in shell scripts.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for the useful feedback, I have updated my answer with your recommendation.

Comment: But a=( $(echo $1/*.pem) ) works retrieve only the first file in the directory

Comment: @aez Both should work; make sure you're testing them correctly. For the first, the `echo` is a second command and must be on a separate line from the assignment (or at least separated with a semicolon, like this: `a=( "$1"/*.pem ); echo "${a[@]}"`. Fir the second, make sure you use `"${a[@]}"` to get all elements of the array -- if you use `$a`, you only get the first element.