# bash loop through files that have no extension

Tags: linux, bash

related to: [Loop through all the files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505047/loop-through-all-the-files-with-a-specific-extension/14505622)

I want to loop through files that matches a pattern:

```
for item in ./bob* ; do
    echo $item
done
```

I have a file list like:

```
bob
bobob
bobob.log
```

I only want to list files that have no extension:

```
bob
bobob
```

what is the best way to archive this? - can I do it in the loop somehow or do I need an if statement within the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash` you can use features of [xtended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob):

```
shopt -s extglob

for item in ./bob!(*.*) ; do
    echo $item
done
```

You can put `shopt -s extglob` in your `.bashrc` file to enable it.

Comment: thanks works nicely - also the other answer does too, I accepted this one somewhat arbitrarily in that I prefer the syntax, but both are good

Answer (score 1):

Recent Bash versions have regular expression support:

```
for f in *
do
  if [[ "$f" =~ .*\..*  ]]
  then
    : ignore
  else
    echo "$f"
  fi
done
```

Comment: thanks works nicely - also the other answer does too, I cant determine which the "accepted answer". So I am just accepting the answer that I used only because it has less (by about 1!?) and is slightly easier to read.