# List md5sum of files on a remote server using ssh and return the output in text file?

Tags: bash, ssh, scp, ls, cp

I have Machine-A and Machine-B and both are Ubuntu servers. Now I want to list all the files on Machine-B using ssh. I want to return the result in a text file so I can analyse the result and the use scp to copy the required files.

```
ssh my_user_name@192.168.150.4 'bash -s tree /f'
ssh my_user_name@192.168.150.4 'bash -s ls -LR'
```

Now this command is not giving the result I wanted. Can anyone help with this so I can list all files on the remote computer using ssh and return the output in the form of a text file.

I am using [ls -LR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105212/linux-recursively-list-all-files-in-a-directory-including-files-in-symlink-direc) to list files and [SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305035/how-to-use-ssh-to-run-shell-script-on-a-remote-machine?noredirect=1&lq=1) to remote script execution.
From the Answer i worked on my problem and iam updating the question to match one little requirement.

I got the list of files throught this command `ssh my_user_name@192.168.150.4 ls /something/sub > output.txt`

But i want the md5sum of all files instead of names because 2 file names might get match.So is there any way to list all files and return all md5sum of all files and return to output.txt file.

Comment: @Inian no i solved the listing and md5 is not solved

Comment: It is telling no such file or directory exists

Comment: @Inian i altered my script with your update

Comment: Yes i did and it do exists.

Comment: @Inian Still the same errro.

Comment: It gave no error now but output.txt file is just empty.

Comment: @Inian It is working if we remove > output.txt

Comment: Then can you re-direct the output to a file in home folder, `> ~/md5output.txt` and now see the contents? And are you using `scp` to copy the files back?

Comment: You could accept the answer( a tick on the left of my answer) to mark it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the file list to a valid path in Machine B and copy it back to Machine A using `scp`

```
ssh username@machineB 'ls -LR /path/to/dir > ~/fileList'
```

To return the `md5sum` of all the files in the directory, use `find` as

```
ssh username@machineB 'find /path/to/dir -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > ~/md5sum_fileList'
```

Now copy the file back to machine A, using a `glob` pattern to copy the files having the pattern `fileList`

```
scp username@machineB:~/*fileList* username@machineA:~/
```

Comment: If you put the `> md5sum_fileList` inside the quotes, then the file is created on the remote host. From what I understand the OP wanted the result in the local host.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Totally agree with you, OP wanted to create the file in the remote machine and copy it back to local using `scp`

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is specify the command, without using "bash". Your default shell will be used on the remote device to execute the command.

```
ssh remote-host command
```

To save the output of your `ls` command to a file, you can simply use the usual shell redirection:

```
ssh remote-host command > output.txt
```

Just in case you end up with multiple file names on a single line, you may need to use `-1` on the `ls` command line. Also, remember that if a filename includes a space, you need quotes in a shell script to support those...

To run multiple commands in a row, although the output won't be as easy to manage, you use quotes and separate commands with semicolons (for example) as in:

```
ssh remote-host "command1; command2; command3" > output.txt
```

In regard to `md5sum`, you can run that against all the files in a directory using the `find` command along with md5sum:

```
ssh remote-host "find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;" > output.txt
```

Change the path (`.` in the example) to whatever works for you.

Comment: Can i make it multiple commands like `cd something/sub ls `.Which moves to another directory and then list files?

Comment: @SaiKiran: Just pass the path as part of the command, i.e. `ls -LR /something/sub > ~/fileList` as in my answer

Comment: @Inian here i have several files inside the folder so can i pass something which returns md5 sum of this files `md5sum ls /somethin/sub`

Comment: @SaiKiran: This is totally a new requirement now. Can you update the question with all your requirements? and let people answer them in one-shot?